# Cisco Jabber and Microsoft Office Integration steps

Tags: office, integration

I am looking for the steps which will guide me to Cisco Jabber and Microsoft Office Integration in order to check the availablity/offline status at SharePoint 2010.

Comment: It isn't a friendly process and it only works in Internet Explorer. Are you sure you want Jabber and not go down the Lync route?

Answer (score 2):

I would evaluate whether [AJAX XMPP library](http://developer.cisco.com/web/cupapi/caxl) could be used by writing a piece of JavaScript that finds the required content on the page and appends presence details. Just like Lync does it *UI-wise*.

Might be a stoopid idea in practice, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Jussi, what you mean is, we get the connect example.html file from the jabber web sdk and put this html as in the body of the content editor web part of SharePoint and  try to run the it ?

Comment: i tried the approach of getting the code jabber samples and tried to run in the browser, but ti shows me error "Could not reach account server".Even I have done all the configurations for connecting to the Cisco presence server, but failed to connect.Can you help, by providing a running/working sample.At the same time, some thread is talking about name.dll . In my server there is no  name.dll .How to install name.dll in my server  and add it as a  plug in to the IE browser?